# android using camera app of device

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to record videos on the android device. The catch is I want to be able to connect to and use the camera app, that records videos and takes pictures, that is already on the phone(default) is there a way of doing this? If so please provide a little detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Intent to request an existing app that provides this service to record the video for you, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html).

```
private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
}
```

Comment: ....how do I reference the camera from from the application?

Comment: ... You don't. The other camera app on the phone records a video, and send you a URI pointing to it.

Comment: soog...I am getting this error startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO) on the line startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
}...do i need to implement or extend a certain method?

Comment: ...Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) from the type Activity

Comment: ...are you calling it from a static method?